# Zeppelin Authentication has a wrong ticket #

Tags: nginx, shiro, apache-zeppelin

I currently the latest zeppelin source running in a master server with HDP 2.5, System is CENTOS 7.2. I have also a worker server. Under the master server, the following entry inside the Zeppelin log:

NotebookServer.java[onMessage]:169) - PING message: invalid ticket c89ae223-65ac-2222-1111-fa46122bafec != fbffe895-1111-1111-8d50-67c2b8fbfbf6

and on the browser I can see a JS error with invalid :
JSESSIONID=6c89ae223-65ac-2222-1111-fa46122bafec

So, If I restart the browser in incognito mode the issues does not happen in the browser, but I can still see the log entry in the server. It will remain there until I restart all services and kill all connections.

I ended up disabling the authentication and now the issue is gone (but I have no authentication)

On the other side, the server is behind 2 proxies, one faces the internet and the other a LAN. I am using a similar proxy configuration as recommended by the guide, the only difference is that I am using a url rewrite.

so, the question is: how can I avoid that issue? How can I flush the current sessions of Zeppelin and force a re-login?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Normally that error happens when your session/ticket has expired and you still have Zeppelin tab open and it keeps sending `ping` messages with old `ticket`. So for example, when you logged in incognito mode, your old ticket will be invalidated, and if your old tab is still open you'll be getting that error on server. For more details, it would be nice to have your scenario from time your start Zeppelin server in order to reproduce same error case. Possibly some related issues could be under [ZEPPELIN-1200](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1200), and [ZEPPELIN-1298](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1298).

Update: it's been addressed under [ZEPPELIN-1298](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1298)